# Usage of "about"-property of creativeObject

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I mark up a webpage about a book with microdata of Schema.org. With the "about"-property of creativeObject type will mark up the book topics. The "about"-property has like expected type a [Thing](http://www.schema.org/CreativeWork).

My questions are:

- Is it right, that here i can use instead of Thing any other, more specific, type, cause Thing is the most generic type?
- Is it not a problem, that i use the "about"-property more than once on the page, applied to describe the same creativeObject?

Thanks and best regards

Evgeniy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1

> Is it right, that here i can use instead of Thing any other, more
>   specific, type, cause Thing is the most generic type?

Sure. More than that - you can use just text if you'd like to (I suppose it is more suitable for book topics). I had the same question a time ago and was redirected to [docs](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected):

> **Expected types vs text.** When browsing the schema.org types, you will
>   notice that many properties have "expected types". This means that the
>   value of the property can itself be an embedded item (see section 1d:
>   embedded items). But this is not a requirement—it's fine to include
>   just regular text or a URL. In addition, whenever an expected type is
>   specified, it is also fine to embed an item that is a child type of
>   the expected type. For example, if the expected type is Place, it's
>   also OK to embed a LocalBusiness.

2

> Is it not a problem, that i use the "about"-property more than once on
>   the page, applied to describe the same creativeObject?

I don't think it is. Last time it was discussed in schema.org WG it was decided that

> Right now, it is always allowed to have multiple values. [for properties]

You can find more [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Singularity#Follow_up_.28June_29th.2C_2012.29) and [here](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/5). But you should keep in mind that all the details of markup usage depends on the specific consumer (Search Engine, etc).